# NSView inconsistent render of custom fonts

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsbutton

I am using a custom font along with an attributed label for my button and every so often the button seems to be rendered differently to how I expect when opening the `NSWindow`.

```
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:centredStyle,
                       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                       [NSFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Bold" size:button_size],
                       NSFontAttributeName,
                       _red,
                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                       nil];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"DELETE ALL" attributes:attrs];
[deleteNotifications setAttributedTitle:attributedString];
```

For some reason that I cannot work out the button is rendered either like (**wrong**):

[image]

or

[image]

Notice that the latter (**correct**) image has the opacity set which the first render seems to neglect and also notice the `NSShadow` also being rendered differently.

---

I cannot identify when the button changes all I do know is that it always starts correctly. I have `setWantsLayer` set to yes after allocating the button:

```
MyButton *deleteNotifications = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(window_width / 2 + (p /2), button_y, window_width /2 - p, 25)];
[deleteNotifications setWantsLayer:YES];
[deleteNotifications.layer setOpacity:min_opac];
[deleteNotifications setOpacity_min:min_opac];
[deleteNotifications setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
```

---

I am also having a similar problem when clicking on a `NSTextField` object where the font becomes bolder than it has been rendered. (I believe the solution to the button will solve this too)

Before click:
[image]

After click (focus):
[image]

---

## MyButton

```
@interface MyButton: NSButton
@property (strong) NSTrackingArea* trackingArea;
@property float opacity_min;
@end

@implementation MyButton
-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super resetCursorRects];
    [self addCursorRect:self.bounds cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
    
    CABasicAnimation *flash = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    flash.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.opacity_min];
    
    NSMutableArray *notifications = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notifications"] mutableCopy];
    if((int)[notifications count] != 0){
        flash.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
    }
    
    flash.duration = 0.2;
    [flash setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [flash setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    flash.repeatCount = 1;
    [self.layer addAnimation:flash forKey:@"flashAnimation"];
}

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    [super resetCursorRects];
    
    CABasicAnimation *flash = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    
    NSMutableArray *notifications = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notifications"] mutableCopy];
    if((int)[notifications count] != 0){
        flash.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
    }
    
    flash.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.opacity_min];
    flash.duration = 0.2;
    [flash setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [flash setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    flash.repeatCount = 1;
    [self.layer addAnimation:flash forKey:@"flashAnimation"];
}

-(void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    if(self.trackingArea != nil) {
        [self removeTrackingArea:self.trackingArea];
    }
    
    int opts = (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways);
    self.trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                     options:opts
                                                       owner:self
                                                    userInfo:nil];
    
    [self addTrackingArea:self.trackingArea];
}
@end
```

---

## hunch

I believe it may have something to do with `makeKeyAndOrderFront` when showing the window.

Comment: NSBlur?  I don't even know what it is.

Comment: @ElTomato sorry, that was stupid of me `NSShadow`

Comment: show your mybutton subclass

Comment: @Pat_Morita please see edit